# Firefox extension - Error: call to Function() blocked by CSP

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have the following simplified code:

**main.js**:

```
var data  = require("sdk/self").data;
var tabs  = require("sdk/tabs");

tabs.on('ready', function(tab) {
  console.log("start");
  let worker = tab.attach({
      contentScriptFile: [
        data.url("jquery.min.js"),
        data.url("test.js")
      ],
  });
  worker.port.emit("start", data.load("popups/start.html"));
  console.log("end");
});
```

**test.js**:

```
console.log("test.js");

self.port.on("start", function (content) {
    console.log("I get the message");
    $('body').append(content);
});
```

**The problem**:
This works just fine and everything is ok in most cases. In only one web site and specifically in well known `github.com`, it produces the following error:

```
console.log: test: start
console.log: test: end
console.error:
  Message: Error: call to Function() blocked by CSP
console.error:
  Message: TypeError: this.sandbox is undefined
  Stack:
    receive@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/content/worker-child.js:75:7
emitOnObject@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/event/core.js:112:9
emit@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/event/core.js:89:38
processMessageReceived@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/remote/child.js:54:38
```

**Note 1**: The problem is with the exchange of the message `start`. But why it is working everywhere else except the `github.com/*`?

**Note 2**: I'm using `cfx`, with `jpm` it works fine. Is any way to fix that or I have to update my extension to run with `jpm`?

Answer (score 1):

cfx is probably including an old version of the SDK while jpm runs with the browser's built-in version. Try running with `--strip-sdk`.

That said, cfx is deprecated, you should use jpm.

---

Github uses [CSP directives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives#Keywords) to block unsafe script execution including `eval` and `new Function()`, many other sites don't.

Newer SDK versions initialize the addon script sandbox differently so it is not affected by CSPs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it's realy helpful. But it answers only the `note 2`. Do you have any idea about the `note 1`? I want not only to fix the problem but also to understand why is producing there. Making your answer more descriptive, it will help me to understand the problem better.

Comment: You shouldn't disguise questions as a footnote.

Comment: Sorry for the footnotes and thanks again for your edit.